# Can all recipe ingredient quantities be halved or doubled without altering taste?

Tags: recipe-scaling

I was wondering if keeping the same proportion of ingredients in a recipe maintains the taste of the food as well. Or are there cases where this simple proportional math doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps the texture will change in some cases because of the type of pans used and the quantity.

Comment: Hi, the question is indeed interesting, but it has been asked before.